# Retrieve course videos based on course id from django rest framework to reactjs using axios

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework, axios

I have created two models course and video.

```
`
class course(models.Model):
    course_name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    course_disc = models.TextField(max_length=2000)
    course_status = models.CharField(max_length=256,choices=[('free','free'),('premium','premium')],default='free')
    course_img = models.ImageField(upload_to="img/",max_length=250,null=True,default=None)
    course_mode = models.CharField(max_length=256,choices=[('ongoing','ongoing'),('completed','completed')],default='ongoing') 

    def __str__(self):
        return self.course_name


class video(models.Model):
    video_title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    video_discription = models.TextField(max_length=2000)
    video_path = models.FileField(upload_to='video/', null=True, verbose_name="")
    course_id = models.ForeignKey(course, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.video_title
`
```

Below are my serializers for course and video. Here **course_id** is the **foreign key** referring to the course model.

```
`
class CourseViewSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = course
        fields = ['id','course_name','course_disc','course_img','course_status']

class VideoViewSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = video
        fields = ['video_title','video_discription','video_path','course_id']
`
```

And my **views.py** file looks like this...here **list** function in both the classes fetch all the records and **retrieve** will fetched records based on id. In **ViewVideo retrieve** function it is fetching all the records based on **course_id**.

```
`
class ViewCourse(viewsets.ViewSet):
   
    def list(self, request):
        queryset = course.objects.all()
        serializer = CourseViewSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        queryset = course.objects.all()
        c = get_object_or_404(queryset, pk=pk)
        serializer = CourseViewSerializer(c)
        return Response(serializer.data)
        
class ViewVideo(viewsets.ViewSet):
    
    def list(self, request):
        queryset = video.objects.all()
        serializer = VideoViewSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        queryset = video.objects.all()
        c = get_object_or_404(queryset, course_id=pk)
        serializer = VideoViewSerializer(c)
        return Response(serializer.data)
`
```

Below is the output after running this video API...you can see the URL, I am passing course_id in the URL and it is returning me the corresponding video to that course_id, in my case it is 6.
URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/video_course/6
output: on django rest framework

```
`
{
    "video_title": "What is Figma?",
    "video_discription": "Figma Introduction with its features.",
    "video_path": "/media/video/videoplayback_EXzlZFT_it236nr.mp4",
    "course_id": 6
}
`
```

Now let me show you on the **react** side...

Actually I m trying to call two APIs using axios in a single react component page i.e CourseDetails.js.

Code of CourseDetails.js Component....

```
`

import React from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { ReactSession } from 'react-client-session';


export default function CourseDetails() {

    const [coursedetail, setCoursesDetail] = useState([]);
    const [videos, setCourseVideo] = useState([]);

    let username =  ReactSession.get("user_name")
    let text = localStorage.getItem("user");
    let obj = JSON.parse(text)
    console.log(obj);

    const  URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000';

    let { id } = useParams();

    const getData = async () => {
        const { data } = await axios.get(`http://localhost:8000/view_course/${id}`);
        setCoursesDetail(data);
    };
    useEffect(() => {
      getData();
    });
    //Below commented api call results in blank screen on react side its not showing any  component rendering
    //when i am trying to call two apis' in a single page.

    const getVideo = async () => {
       const { videodata } = await axios.get(`http://localhost:8000/video_course/${id}`);
       setCourseVideo(videodata);
     };

     useEffect(() => {
        getVideo();
     });


     return(
       <div className="row justify-content-cener">
          <div className="col-lg-8">

           <h3 id="title">{videos.video_title}</h3>
  
           <video id='video' controls controlsList="nodownload" style={{"width" : "100%"}}>
               <source id="player" src={`${URL}${videos.video_path}`} type="video/mp4" />
           </video>
           <p id="desc" style={{"marginTop " : "10px", "fontSize" : "16px"}}> {videos.video_description}</p>
        </div>
)
}

`
```

This is how i m trying to call **video_course** API.

Now my question is...

How can i call 2 APIs in a single react component using axios in which video_course api in dependent on view_course api becoz of foreign key?

And how i can display this video path in my react jsx? is the way I've shown to display video_path is correct in jsx syntax? if not then plz guide me through it also.

Also help me how the URL would be on react side after calling 2 APIs.

Thank you in advance :)

**Final Solution:**

For this I had to create DTO(Data Transfer Object) to retrieve all the videos of the corresponding course. Let me show you the output first:

```
    {
        "course_disc": "Figma is a very powerful application that runs online. There are virtually no platform boundaries when it comes to using figma because you can design within a web browser or using their desktop application made for windows and macs. Figma is similar to Sketch and Adobe XD but is the more powerful of the three when it comes to team collaboration and responsive, fast paced design. This course will cover user interface designing using the powerful tools within Figma.",
        "course_img": "img/figma-brands_6jR7YRb.png",
        "course_mode": "ongoing",
        "course_name": "Figma",
        "course_status": "premium",
        "videos": [
            {
                "video_discription": "Introduction Part 1",
                "video_path": "video/videoplayback_8vrcgxy_u5qBkNQ.mp4",
                "video_title": "What is Figma?"
            },
            {
                "video_discription": "Features of Figma Part 2",
                "video_path": "video/video1_HppJ0va.mp4",
                "video_title": "Figma Features"
            }
        ]
    }
```

This was the actual output I wanted. Now let me show you the code i have done.

I have created one folder name **dtos** where my **views.py** file is there. Inside **dtos** folder I have created one python file **CourseDto.py**. Inside that file below is the code I have written:

**CourseDto.py**

```
import jsons

class VideoDto(jsons.JsonSerializable):
    
    def __init__(self, video):
        self.video_title = video.video_title
        self.video_discription = video.video_discription
        self.video_path = str(video.video_path)

class CourseDto(jsons.JsonSerializable):
    
    def __init__(self, course, videos):
        self.course_name = course.course_name
        self.course_disc = course.course_disc
        self.course_status = course.course_status
        self.course_img = str(course.course_img)
        self.course_mode = course.course_mode
        self.videos = list()
        
        for video in videos:
            self.videos.append(VideoDto(video))
```

Now in **serializers.py** you just only need to create **serializer** for fetching all courses only. (i.e., actually done in **list** function of **ViewCourse** class in **views.py** file)

```
class CourseViewSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = course
        fields = ['id','course_name','course_img','course_status']
```

Now in **views.py** file my **ViewCourse** class is:

```
class ViewCourse(viewsets.ViewSet):
    def list(self, request):
        queryset = course.objects.all()
        serializer = CourseViewSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        c = course.objects.get(pk=pk)
        videos = list(video.objects.filter(course_id=c.pk))
        dto = CourseDto(c, videos)
        return Response(dto.json)
```

And that's it. After that just create url in **urls.py** like this:

```
    path('view_course',ViewCourse.as_view({'get': 'list'})),
    path('view_course/<pk>',ViewCourse.as_view({'get': 'retrieve'}))
```

I hope this will help you.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think rather than calling two apis, you can create a different serializer which returns the video data with the `retrieve` request. A code snippet For example:

```
class CourseViewSerializerWithId(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    videos = VideoViewSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = course
        fields = ['id','course_name','course_disc','course_img','course_status', 'videos']
```

The new course view would look like this:

```
class ViewCourse(viewsets.ViewSet):

    def list(self, request):
        queryset = course.objects.all()
        serializer = CourseViewSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        queryset = course.objects.all()
        c = get_object_or_404(queryset, pk=pk)
        serializer = CourseViewSerializerWithId(c)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

I think this way, you don't have to make complex multiple dependent API calls from the frontend.

Comment: But this solution is not working when my course does not have any videos in it. Like course_id = 6 have videos but course_id = 5 doesn't have any videos. So, how can i filtered that ? Becoz i want course details no matter if that course is having any videos or not.

Comment: This serializer will return a course with id even if it doesn't have videos. in case there are no videos, an empty list will be returned on `videos` field

Comment: But that was not working.....there no doubt in your logic .. i tried to apply your logic ....but then it gives me an error saying, that "course has not attribute like videos". So after lots of struggle I finally found solution to this using DTO. By creating dto and converting it into serializer and then passing it works well in my case. I'll update the procedure that I'd gone through to solve it by tomorrow so everyone can get what exactly I've done....BTW thanx for your help @SihanTawsik :) well will not down work your answer but will ask to update if possible.